# Python Requests: POST JSON and file (multiform data) in 1 single request

Tags: java, json, python-2.7, jersey

From client side (using python) I want to send both json data and file as part of single request using multiform-data but not able to achieve this. On server side I have Jersey which is working fine if I send the request using curl but if the same request is sent using Python then it doesn't work as Jersey crashes.

python-requests package version 0.8.2-1. I cannot upgrade to latest version as this is the latest version available for ubuntu 12.04.

Below curl request works fine and server is able to process the request successfully with below curl.

```
curl -v -k -u "test:" -F file=@/tmp/test_new.zip --form upload_info='{"id": "1234", "test": "testing"}' -X POST "https://IP/test_api"
```

Snippet of the server side code

```
    @POST
    @Path("/test_api")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response testAPIHandler(
                    @HeaderParam("Authorization") String auth,
                    @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
                    @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail,
                    @FormDataParam("upload_info") JSONObject jsonData) throws IOException {
             try {
                    id = jsonData.getString("id");
                    url = jsonData.getString("test");
                 }
```

This is this python code but doesn't work. Even tried to send upload_info as nested json with keyname as 'upload_info' that didn't work either.

```
def test_upload():
    url = "https://IP/api/test_api"
    user = "test"
    passwd = None
    upload_info = {'id': '1234', 'test': "testing"}
    filepath = "/tmp/test_new.zip"
    json_data = simplejson.dumps(upload_info)

    fileobj = open(filepath, 'rb')
    files = {'file' : ('test_new.zip', fileobj)}

    headers = {'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data'}
    r = requests.post(url, files=files, data=json_data, auth=(user, passwd), headers=headers)

    print r.status_code

test_upload()
```

When I send the request using Python I get this exception on Server side

```
May 25, 2015 9:35:03 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException
SEVERE: The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.jersey.multipart.impl.MultiPartReaderClientSide.unquoteMediaTypeParameters(MultiPartReaderClientSide.java:227)
    at com.sun.jersey.multipart.impl.MultiPartReaderClientSide.readMultiPart(MultiPartReaderClientSide.java:154)
    at com.sun.jersey.multipart.impl.MultiPartReaderServerSide.readMultiPart(MultiPartReaderServerSide.java:80)
    at com.sun.jersey.multipart.impl.MultiPartReaderClientSide.readFrom(MultiPartReaderClientSide.java:144)
    at com.sun.jersey.multipart.impl.MultiPartReaderClientSide.readFrom(MultiPartReaderClientSide.java:82)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest.getEntity(ContainerRequest.java:488)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest.getEntity(ContainerRequest.java:552)
    at com.sun.jersey.multipart.impl.FormDataMultiPartDispatchProvider$FormDataInjectableValuesProvider.getInjectableValues(FormDataMultiPartDispatchProvider.java:122)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$EntityParamInInvoker.getParams(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:153)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:203)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1511)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1442)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1391)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1381)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:200)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Are you able to make a call without the file, just with params to some other Resource method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending both files and data param as part of requests.post() didn't work for me so what I ended up doing was to send json data as input stream. I converted JSON data to StringIO on Python side and then sent the StringIO object as another file object in "files" param and on the Server side I received it as InputStream which I converted to JSONObject to get required values.

Jersey code on Server:

```
    @POST
    @Path("/test_upload_files")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response testHandler(
                    @HeaderParam("Authorization") String auth,
                    @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
                    @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail,
                    @FormDataParam("json_data") InputStream jsonStream) throws IOException {
            String encoding = "UTF-8";
            JSONObject jsonObject;

            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

            IOUtils.copy(jsonStream, writer, encoding);

            String input = writer.toString();

            try {
                    jsonObject = new JSONObject(input);
                    id = jsonObject.getString("id");
                    country = jsonObject.getString("country");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                    return null;
            }

    }
```

Here is Python code to send:

```
import simplejson
import requests
from cStringIO import StringIO

def upload_files_and_json():
    url = "https://IP/test_upload_files"
    user = "foo"
    passwd = None
    upload_info = {'id': '1234', 'country': 'zzz'}
    filepath = "/tmp/test.zip"
    json_data = simplejson.dumps(upload_info)
    json_input = StringIO(json_data)

    fileobj = open(filepath, 'rb')
    files = {'file' : ('test.zip', fileobj), 'json_data': json_input}

    r = requests.post(url, files=files, auth=(user, passwd))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i tried with [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/install/) package installed

```
import requests    

class RestCall:

    if __name__ == '__main__':

        url = "http://url.com/rest/doj/webservice/helloge"

        data = dict(fn='Test', ln='Me')

        r = requests.post(url, data=data, allow_redirects=True)
        print (r.content)
```

your server component looks like below

```
@POST
@Path("/helloge")
@Produces("text/plain")
public String helloGe(@FormParam("fn") String fn,@FormParam("ln") String ln){
    return "Hello "+fn+" "+ln;    
}
```

Your output is:

```
b'Hello Test Me'
```

Comment: FormParam is not there in the Jersey 1.17 and sending both files and data didn't work.

Comment: You can even use JAXRS based on your need and by using a binding tool it can make life a lot easier. Anyway also update your code with answer so that others can reference it.